# Lua 5.4.0/LuaRocks installation

Tags: lua, luarocks

*Hello,*

I have been using Lua 5.1.2 since I begun learning Lua, and I wanted to upgrade to a more recent version, but there aren't any tutorial on how to do it, and I never did something similar. I downloaded the Lua 5.4.0 binaries, but I don't know how to install LuaRocks, which is really useful. (I don't know if this information is useful, but I'm using Windows 7)

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

so you got 5.4.0 installed?

https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Download
you probably want the 64-bit version of LuaRocks
if it complains, try the 32-bit instead.

just guessing, because most processors are 64-bit these days - unless it's something like a Raspberry Pi, but then you wouldn't be on Win7...

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
I installed the "Windows all-in-one executable (64-bit)" on the site you said, but when I run the file (through prompt) it says that LUA_INCDIR and LUA_LIBDIR are missing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the latest version of Luarocks needs Lua 5.3 and will not function with Lua 5.4.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the latest version of Luarocks needs Lua 5.3 and will not function with Lua 5.4. – Jonathan"

No, that's blatent misinformation.  `luaver use 5.4.2 && luarocks install luafilesystem`  luafilesystem 1.8.0-1 is now installed in ...